# jQuery after dynamically creating elements by append couldn't return htmldivelement. Instead it returns object

Tags: jquery, append

```
$("#mainMenu").children('li').eq(0).children('a').bind({
    click : function() {
```

Here I'm clearing blocks aside and section. And dynamically creating them by appending `worksParser();`.

```
        $('aside > *').remove();
        $('section > *').remove();
        worksParser();
```

And here I want to call function fromAsideToSection. And send dom element `$('aside').children('.workExample')` just appended to block aside.

```
        var x = $('aside').children('.workExample');
        alert(x);
        fromAsideToSection.call(x);
```

But x return `(object object)`, instead of `(object HtmlDivElement)`. How I can send `(object HtmlDivElement`) to function?

```
    }
});

function worksParser() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "base.xml",
        dataType : "xml",
        success : function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('siteExample').each(function() {
                var name_dump = $(this).attr('name');
                var mediaType_dump = $(this).attr('mediaType');
                var media_dump = $(this).attr('media');
                var video_dump = $(this).text();
                var description_dump = $(this).attr('description');
                var url_dump = $(this).attr('url');

                if (mediaType_dump != 'video') {
                    $('aside').append('<div class="workExample"><div class="mediaName">' + name_dump + '</div><div class="exampleMedia"><img src="' + media_dump + '" alt="" /></div><div class="descrExample" style="display: none">' + description_dump + '</div><div class="urlExample" style="display: none">' + url_dump + '</div></div><div class="separator"></div>');
                } else {
                    $('aside').append('<div class="workExample"><div class="mediaName">' + name_dump + '</div><div class="exampleMedia"><img src="' + media_dump + '" alt="" /></div><div class="descrExample" style="display: none">' + description_dump + '</div><div class="videoExample" style="display: none">' + video_dump + '</div></div><div class="separator"></div>');
                }
            });
        }
    });
}


function fromAsideToSection() {
    alert(this);
    if ($(this).children('.videoExample').length > 0) {
        $('section > *').remove();
        $('section').append('<div id="mediaName" class="mediaName">' + $(this).children(".mediaName").text() + '</div><div id="mediaBlock"></div><div id="mediaMore">Описание</div><div id="mediaDescription">' + $(this).children('.descrExample').text() + '</div>');
        $('section').children('#mediaBlock').append($(this).children(".videoExample").children().clone("withDataAndEvents, deepWithDataAndEvents"));

    } else {
        $('section > *').remove();
        $('section').append('<div id="mediaName" class="mediaName">' + $(this).children(".mediaName").text() + '</div><div id="mediaBlock"><a target="_blank" style="" href="' + $(this).children('.exampleMedia').children('img').attr('src') + '"> <img src=' + $(this).children('.exampleMedia').children('img').attr('src') + ' alt="1.jpg"></a></div><div id="mediaMore">Описание</div><div id="mediaDescription">' + $(this).children('.descrExample').text() + '</div>');
    }
    sectHeight = null;
    oldHeight = null;
    sectHeight = $('section').height();
    $('aside').height(sectHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) *

```
x.get();
```

[simple fiddle based on your submission](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/xKKvY/)

Buuut, your function `fromAsideToSection` (which is cut-off by the way) is using `$(this)` so if this is an element or a jQuery object it doesn't matter -- jQuery will recognize it and `$(this)` will end up being essentially the same thing whether `this` is a jQuery object or the DOM elements.  I stressed that in the fiddle.

**Not to be confused with the ajax shorthand jQuery.get() ref: api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/*

Comment: I add full function fromAsideToSection. But x.get() doesn't help

Comment: The problem isn't `x.get()` as i demonstrated, but it does answer the question asked.  

To solve this new question we might need to see the markup. However, one red flag is that you have `$('aside').children('.workExample')` but just above it you have `$('aside > *').remove();`   

If all of this is in the same script (the click handler) then `x` will be empty and fail the test `if ($(this).children('.videoExample').length > 0)`

Comment: But after removing all I appending all back here works Parser(); And I just now try to comment removing. Problem not solved

Comment: I just tested for $('aside').children('.workExample').length It's equal to '0'. I don't understand. Before that I appending this elements in func worksParser(); Why their length = 0?

Comment: `worksParser();` is asynchronous so it's likely appending to `aside` AFTER your call to `fromAsideToSection`.

You can move the calls to `fromAsideToSection` to a callback for `worksParser()` or you can setup a deffered object to resolve when `worksParser()` is "done".

Comment: I really hope that no one suggests you use `async : false` in your `worksParser()` however, that would be a quick-and-dirty way to test what the asynchronous theory I suggested above.

Comment: Thank you! I put fromAsideToSection() after parsing XML. And without async:false.